# Determine the user action i.e yes/no, when chrome alert to launch an application in Javascript

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to capture a confirmation box message if a user has selected **yes** or **no**, when chrome gives an alert box like "https://xxxxxxx:8080 wants to open this application".

Is there any way to catch this action result from Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

var x = window.confirm("Do you really want to leave?");

console.log(x);

Value of X will be True if User selects OK else false.